# ionic 3 - AdMob está com Erro ao coloca-lo no APP

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic, ionic2, admob

Quando vou colocar o AdMob na minha aplicação ionic ele fica do jeito da foto abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual seria o erro para n estar mostrando os anúncios ??

Código que uso:

```
displayBanner() {
if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
  // we will just use a test id for this tutorial
  id: 'ca-app-pub-9249962217154699/5959043893',
  isTesting: true,
  autoShow: true,
  bannerAtTop:true // default is false
};

 this.adMob.banner.config(bannerConfig);

  this.adMob.banner.prepare().then((result)=>{
    console.log(result);
  },(reason)=>{
    console.log(reason);
  });

}

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta colocar o `isTesting: false` ao inves de `isTesting: true`.